# Replace Non-Alphanumeric Characters in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, replace

I am trying to convert a string in Oracle into a modified string that is compatible with a specific API.

I would like to leave all alphanumeric characters intact, replace all spaces with the + character, and replace all special characters with % plus their hex code.

For example,

**Project 1: Nuts & Bolts**

should become

**Project+1%3A+Nuts+%26+Bolts**

Is there any way to do this using only SQL?

Comment: I don't know of a way other than nesting `REPLACE` function calls, one for each character translation. The `TRANSLATE` function is tantalizingly close, but it can only replace a single character with another single character. I think you're stuck with a user-defined function, but once you have one you can call easily enough from SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can get there with plain SQL without nested `replace` calls. You can get your sample value with the [`utl_url.escape()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_url.htm#ARPLS71589), but because you have to pass it a second parameter and that is a boolean, you have to do it in an PL/SQL block:

```
set define off
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(replace(utl_url.escape('Project 1: Nuts & Bolts', true),
    '%20', '+'));
end;
/

Project+1%3A+Nuts+%26+Bolts
```

The `url_utl.escape` function converts the spaces to `%20`:

```
Project%201%3A%20Nuts%20%26%20Bolts
```

... and the single `replace` call converts those to `+`.

As Ed Gibbs said, you can make that a function so you can at least call it from plain SQL:

```
create or replace function my_escape(str in varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
    return replace(utl_url.escape(str, true), '%20', '+');
end;
/

set define off
select my_escape('Project 1: Nuts & Bolts') from dual;

MY_ESCAPE('PROJECT1:NUTS&BOLTS')
--------------------------------
Project+1%3A+Nuts+%26+Bolts
```

You probably need to check the legal and reserved character lists to see if there's anything else that needs special handling.

(I've used [`set define off`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG073) to stop my client treating the ampersand as a substitution variable; your client or application might not need that, e.g. if calling over JDBC).

Comment: Can you amend the documentation link. Its not working

Comment: @Raj_Te - done; happens a lot with Oracle doc links. I quite often see old answers being edited by other people to fix them, so feel free to d the same if you come across any.

Comment: One more correction, If i execute your block or query, it will ask for input literals. So either you need to declare at the beginning "set define off" or modify the input string as ==='Project 1: Nuts '||'&'||' Bolts'====

Comment: That's client specific, but yes, I guess my demo was done in SQL Developer so I must have turned it off.

Answer (score 0):

apex_util.url_encode should work.